# unexpected return value from member function

Tags: c++, constructor

I am writing a program for quadratic equation but in the middle of the program there's an error such that it always returns `0`

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
class quardaticequation {
public:
    float a, b, c, sqr, descriminat;

    quardaticequation( float x, float y, float z ) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
    }

    //seems to always return 0 after use of contstructor
    float getDescriminant() {
        sqr = pow( b, 2.0 );
        sqr;
        descriminat = sqr - 4 * ( a * c);
        return descriminat;
    }
};

int main() {
    float first, second, third;
    cout << "please enter the number in float format";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "please enter the second  number in float format";
    cin >> second;
    cout << "please enter  the third number in float format";
    cin >> third;
    quardaticequation q( first, second, third );
    cout << q.getDescriminant(); //ALWAYS RETURNS 0
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your assignments are back to front — you wrote `x=a;` where you needed `a=x;`, etc.  There are other problems (the line `sqr;` is a no-op, for example).

Comment: Your includes should have a space after them, `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: @PlasmaPower: syntactically, the space is not mandatory; aesthetically, it should be there.

Comment: because i havent complete my program yet

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have completed your program or not; you should write proper and readable code from start to finish; particularly if you want to post it online.  That means proper and consistent formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't your constructor wrong?

```
quardaticequation(float x,float y,float z){
    x=a;
    y=b;
    z=c;
}
```

should be

```
quardaticequation(float x,float y,float z){
    a=x;
    b=y;
    c=z;
}
```

Comment: thanks was a little mistake but thanks for assitance but now i am confuse that what answer i should accept .

Comment: Better still, use an initialiser list. Then it would be impossible to make this mistake.

Comment: Or, better, `quardaticequation(float x, float y, float z) : a(x), b(y), c(z) { …maybe set sqr and descriminat… }` or maybe remove them from the class as unnecessary (could be local variables in `getDescriminant()`).

Comment: @Vicky: your choice — which helped you most?  In case of doubt, probably accept the earlier of the equally helpful answers.  You can up-vote multiple answers — that's perfectly kosher if the answers helped.

Comment: all the guys give me the correct answers what should i do now it will be unjustice

Comment: @Vicky don't worry, just pick the earliest one or the one you like the most for any reason. Or pick none at all, your call :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler While optimization probably doesn't matter for this exercise, if you use them often enough it can be quite useful to have them as members so that they are only recomputed only they need to be, despite potentially many uses from many different functions externally. speed/memory trade off of course, so YMMV :-p

Comment: @UpAndAdam: my concern was that the constructor did not ensure that all members of the class are appropriately initialized.  Either the constructor should set the `sqr` and `discriminat` to known states (not leave them uninitialized) or the members could be dropped.  I'm fine with eager evaluation — though it depends on how often each equation will be solved.  What is bad (in my book, and I think Scott Meyers' books, too) is not initializing members in the constructor.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed 100% that should be bad in all books.  I utilize a compiler warning for it which is raised to be an Error so sometimes I forget to look for it by eye. (actually I treat all warnings as errors :-P )

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in the value assingments in your constructor:

```
x=a;
y=b;
z=c;
```

should be

```
a=x;
b=y;
c=z;
```

Even better as suggested by another member would be use an initializer list:

```
quardaticequation(float x,float y,float z)
: a(x), b(y), c(z)
{
}
```

Comment: thanks was my little mistake but have wrote 30 program before thats why i am completely muff right now thanks for assistance

Comment: @Vicky muff right now? what does muff mean?

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
sqr;
```

Does absolutely nothing and should not be in you program.

The reason this does not work is because you have an error in your constructor. Take a look at what is being assigned where.

Comment: your totally on wrong path remove your answer

Comment: The preliminary observation is accurate; the statement does nothing (including 'does no harm', though it also does no good). The rest of the answer is not helpful.

Comment: sqr is a float variable which is storing the b2 value so how could be possible that you are saying that does absolutely nothing

Comment: The specific line that reads `sqr;` does nothing. `sqr` is assigned before that and used after it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: the first part of your comment is correct but misleading about the answer. the second part of your comment is wrong (I think misguided, but you don't elucidate *why* you think this correct and most helpful answer is not helpful).

Comment: @Vicky: the answer may have been edited after your comment, but as it stands currently, your comment first is wrong, and your second comment does not quite make sense to me (possibly because you have some misunderstanding that I don't know about and can't imagine).

Comment: +1 for teaching how to fish.

Comment: but i don't know he is mention sqr and than he is pointing out the constuctor and after all this he is saying what is being assign where. if u cant explain in short it means you don't understand.A good quote by some one.